# Find recursion for number of strings length of n above {$A,B,C$} without AA and BB

Tags: recursion

Okay, I tried something, got close, but no idea why my answer is wrong.
I pick C >> $n-1$ options.
I Pick A (Here is problem):
A = n-1 options -(subtracting) (AB = n-2 options - ABB = n-3 options))
Which gets me:
$a_n = 2a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}$
Why is my answer wrong? I used the two mistakes.
Why is it: $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$

Comment: @lulu Oh I remember you, you helped me once hehe, thanks for before :)
About this question, I see what you say,although yea, its almost the same. but anyway, I want to know why my solution is wrong, I used the problems.

Comment: Also, problem is I dont use series of an, bn, cn, I saw a video regarding this, but he used an bn and cn, whoever will think of using such stuff.. I use only an

Comment: As I understand your approach, you are prepending a character before a substring that is already without AA and BB. You have consider the strings with first character either A or C; what about those that start with B?

Comment: @peterwhy hmm, you mean to add the case of start with B? Ill update in a minute.

Comment: You wrote to subtract those "(AB = n-2 options - ABB = n-3 options)", which is to subtract the number of strings that have length $n$ and start with either ABA or ABC. May I understand why to subtract this?

Comment: @peterwhy because BB and AA are not good. and I saw a trick like this in other exercise.

Comment: Can't really follow your approach.  I'd do it by conditioning on the starting term.  Let $A_n,B_n, C_n$ denote good strings that begin with $A,B,C$.  $T_n=A_n+B_n+C_n$ is the total.  Then $C_n=T_{n-1}$, $A_n=B_{n-1}+C_{n-1}$ and $B_n=A_{n-1}+C_{n-1}$ and, of course $A_n=B_n$.  That's enough.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, but I dont use mini-series for it, I dont do $a_n$ $b_n$ $c_n$ and such.. I use only $a_n$

Comment: Sure, but as I say I really can't follow your reasoning.

Comment: @lulu I dont have time to study that thing, the test is tommorow :\ ( final exam )

Comment: It's hard to just consider the start without conditioning, because a good string could begin $ABABAB\cdots$ or something like that.  You don't know that you'll ever get to a $C$.  But the conditioning makes it easy to handle.

Comment: Can't help you there.  Conditioning on the start of a string is a standard counting method, it's not exotic.  Good luck.

Comment: @lulu Thanks anyway :) I will try to see how to answer this question my way :)

Comment: I understand that AA and BB are not good; but you tried to remove ABA... and ABC... strings from A... strings, and that remains strings that start with either (3-substrings) AAB, AAC, ACA, ACB, or ACC. Some not-good strings are still here, and some good strings are gone.

Comment: @peterwhy ahh, I will try to see what to do, I dont know what to do, but I will try my hardest and see :\ Thanks

Comment: If you continue with @lulu 's approach, then $$\begin{align*}
T_n &= A_n + B_n + C_n\\
&= \underbrace{(B_{n-1}+C_{n-1})+(A_{n-1}}_{T_{n-1}}+C_{n-1}) + T_{n-1}\\
&= T_{n-1}+T_{n-2} + T_{n-1}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @peterwhy Thanks, but I will return to it later, I will try again after clearing my head from the exercise :)